# How to get a line file from a class in an other class?

Tags: python, class, parsing

My question is really simple. Let me explain my problem with an exemple code. I have developed a specific file parser and each line represents an object.

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")

class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1   // first line

    def readFile(self):
        for line in file:
            test2()
            // do things..


class Line():
    def printLine(self):
        f.readline() // Need to read the current line from the readFile() loop 


test()
```

So, what I would like to know is how can I get access to the current line from `readFile()` in `test2().printLine()` without reopening the file ?

Comment: Why not just add `line` as an argument of `printLine()` ?

Comment: Hint: as you may or may not know, in your case it might be better to have the file contents loaded at once( `lines = file.readlines()` in a global, maybe) than having each object opening/reading/closing it locally.

Comment: @GomesJ.A. I would not recommend thinking about such optimizations until they are actually needed. They may or may not be true anyways. There may be several levels of optimization running behind the scenes. It is way more important to design a clean code.

Comment: Why do you define classes (`Reader`, `Line`) and only call unrelated functionc (`test`, `test2`). Without more clarification this it at least *unclear*

Comment: @PatrickMichel It seems that you made your source less understandable with the recent edit.

Comment: @zvone: I made that suggestion in the sense of code clarity, not exactly as an optimization. You are perfectly correct, but the question is not clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is neither really Pythonic nor even OO. After reading the original question I think that what you need should look like:

```
file_name = "file.txt"

class Reader(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name             # store file name as a data member

    def readFile(self):
        with open(self.name, "r") as file:  # with ensure proper close of file
                                            #   using data member name
            for line in file:               # iterate on lines
                Line(line).printline()      # pass the line to another object
                # or: test2(line)           # or to a function
                # do other things...

class Line:                       # an auxilliary class
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
    def printLine(self):
        # use self.line here

def test2(line):                  # a module level function
    # use line here

Reader(file_name).readFile()      # create a new Reader object and calls its readfile method
```

Comment: re: pythonic: read_file() :)

Answer (score 1):

Functions take arguments and return values. Use those features. Send the line:

```
def readFile():
    for line in file:
        test2(line)    #  <-- send line to test2
        // do things...
```

Comment: This don't work, I do not receive the line in the Line() class

Comment: @PatrickMichel Because half of the code is missing (in your question as well as here). `test2` is not defined, but I suppose it somehow ends up calling `printLine` method of class `Line`. Fix the question and I'll add the missing part to the answer as well.